# Issue with Selection of 2D Drawings in Autodesk Forge Viewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

In our specific scenario, we have successfully loaded two viewers into the same window, creating a split-screen configuration with a 2D view on the left side and a 3D view on the right side. Our objective is to establish a connection between the 3D element and the selected 2D element.

However, we have encountered a challenge in that only one of the two drawings on a single 2D sheet can be selected. Regrettably, the second drawing on the same sheet remains unselectable.

We are reaching out to seek guidance on how to address this issue and enable the selection of both 2D drawings on a single sheet. Any insights or recommendations you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

[screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGld5.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not managing the viewer's resources the right way. It's hard to find the issue without looking into the code. Meanwhile, exact functionality is available in this sample, you might want to look into this or just reuse part of the code.

Demo: https://aps-plant-operation.autodesk.io/

Code: https://github.com/autodesk-platform-services/aps-plant-operation